# SD card data parsing with esp8266

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I need some assistance for extracting data from a SD card I based my code from [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-do-i-split-an-incoming-string?newreg=be512501f951445e846fa0326e599855) section.

The code works when I read the data from the SD card and display it into the serial port, but when I pass the data into an char* array and call a function that will loop the array, the array displays garbage (some unreadable data). I am trying to make a function which I can use to call different settings stored from SD card in a text file format.

I have a global variable named:

```
char* tempStoreParam[10];
```

Which will store temporary data to be process. The data stored in the text file is in this format

`-n.command`

Where: n = int number and index location of the data to be stored in the `tempStoreParam[10]` and command is a char* array to stored in `tempStoreParam[10]`.

Example:

`-1.readTempC`

`-2.readTempF`

`-3.setdelay:10`

`-4.getIpAddr`

Here is the code snippet:

```
while (sdFiles.available()) {
  char sdData[datalen + 1];
  byte byteSize = sdFiles.read(sdData, datalen);
  sdData[byteSize] = 0;
  char* mList = strtok(sdData, "-");
  while (mList != 0)
  {
    // Split the command in 2 values
    char* lsParam = strchr(mList, '.');
    if (lsParam != 0)
    {
      *lsParam = 0;
      int index = atoi(mList);
      ++lsParam;
      tempStoreParam[index] = lsParam;
      Serial.println(index);
      Serial.println(tempStoreParam[index]);
    }
    mList = strtok(0, "-");
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the following result:

```
char* tempStoreParam[10] = {"readTempC","readTempF","setdelay:10","getIpAddr"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems - In order:

The return value of read in this instance is a 32 bit integer - You are truncating it to a byte value, meaning if the file contents are ever over 255 bytes, you will incorrectly terminate your string, and fail to read the contents correctly:

```
byte byteSize = sdFiles.read(sdData, datalen);
```

Secondly, you are storing the address of a stack variable into your `tempStoreParam` array with this line:

```
tempStoreParam[index] = lsParam;
```

Now, this will work, but only for how long `sdData` remains in scope. After that, `sdData` is no longer valid to use, most likely leading to the garbage you experience. What you most likely are trying to do is take a copy of the data to place it into `tempStoreParam`. To do that, you should use something like this:

```
// The amount of memory we need is the length of the string, plus one 
// for the null byte
int length = strlen(lsParam)+1

// Allocate storage space for the length of lsParam in tempStoreParam
tempStoreParam[index] = new char[length];

// Make sure the allocation succeeded 
if (tempStoreParam[index] != nullptr) {
   // Copy the string into our new container
   strncpy(tempStoreParam[index], lsParam, length);
}
```

At this point, you should be able to pass around that string outside the function successfully. As a note, you will need to `delete` the array created once you are done with it / before reading the file again.